# Changing Notification Center preferences programatically or from the command line

Tags: notifications, automation, system-settings, defaults, sqlite

*(There's plenty of questions about toggling Do Not Disturb programmatically, this is different)*

Is there a plist file or sqlite DB that can be modified to change these settings programmatically? Specifically, "Show notifications on lock screen", "Show in Notification Center", etc.

I would like to change these in bulk, and sync those changes between my machines.

[image: A screenshot of the macOS system settings, with the Notifications pref pane open, focused on the Mail app.]

(I happen to be using the Venura Beta, but this question applies equally to Monteray).

I found `NCUtil`, but things have changed since it was written.

- It expects there to be a SQLite DB at `$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)com.apple.notificationcenter/db/db`,
- but it's now at `$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)com.apple.notificationcenter/db/db`, which has a different
  schema (e.g. there's no more `app_info` table with a `flags` column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the file name is `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ncprefs.plist`
you can modify `flags` value for your app in that file to "Show notifications on lock screen" or "Show in Notification Center".

The file is in plist binary format. You can convert it in xml format for obeserving the flag values. Use below command:

```sh
plutil -convert xml1 "/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ncprefs.plist"
```

Change the settings from System Preferences and observe the desired value and then set it programatically using `PlistBuddy`

Providing you sample code to forcefully turn on notifications for your app

```sh
#!/bin/sh
notification_plist="/Users/$user/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ncprefs.plist"

#Count of the bundles existing in the plist
count=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :apps" "${notification_plist}" | grep -c "bundle-id")

for ((index=1; index<"${count}"; index++)); do
    bundle_id=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print apps:${index}:bundle-id" "${notification_plist}");
            if [[ "${bundle_id}" == <your app bundle id> ]]; then
                    flags_value=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print apps:${index}:flags" "${notification_plist}");
                    echo $flags_value $index
                    
                    if [[ $flags_value == 276* ]]; then
                        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :apps:${index}:flags 41951246" "${notification_plist}"
                    fi
            fi
done

# Restart notification center to make changes take effect.
killall sighup usernoted
```

Note: You need to restart the `usernoted` service binary for changes to take effect, just kill it macOS will immediately start it again. The solution is tested on macOS Big Sur and Monterey.

Comment: Oh wow, this is great! Thanks for taking the time to write this up!

Comment: What is the significance of `41951246` and `276`?  What if I wanted to turn a notification off?